# Form is not submitting via Firefox

Tags: html, ajax, forms, laravel, firefox

I've a form that works perfectly fine on Chrome, Safari, but not Firefox.

## Try#1

```
<form id="subscribe-form" class="footer-sign-up" action="/subscribe" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" id="fname" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="lname" required>
    <input id="footer-email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" required>
    

    <input type="submit" id="subscribe" class="signupbtn" value="sign up">

</form>
```

---

## Try#2

```
<form id="subscribe-form" class="footer-sign-up" action="/subscribe" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" id="fname" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="lname" required>
    <input id="footer-email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" required>
    
    
    <button type="submit" id="subscribe" class="signupbtn">sign up</button>

</form>
```

---

## result

[image]

**Network Tab**

[image]

**Header**
[image]

**Params**

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: any errors in the console when you submit?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in FireFox's debugger? `F12` should open it, and you can check the `Console` and `Network` tabs for Front/Back-end errors (respectively)

Comment: @Jeff, console seem clean. I got this error `The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again. `

Comment: @TimLewis, in Network Tab, I see 2 POSTs. 1 is `200`, 1 is `419`, will add screenshot into the post.

Comment: What's in the `Response` tab there?

Comment: Hmm... Tested in a local dev environment, and I can't recreate any issues with this form... `Echo`ing your form to a page and submitting has no issue (once I add in the `csrf_field()`) in any browser.

Comment: @TimLewis, response show nothing in there.

Comment: @TimLewis Maybe I miss something on my  meta section ?

Comment: @TimLewis, not sure if this help, but this the IP of my staging site, all the way down, you will see the form that I have. 

http://159.89.178.148

Comment: Yup; that does help, testing now. `t@test.com` and `test@test.com`, if you need to remove any data I input. You're submitting via Ajax aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found something; if you're submitting via AJAX, but not preventing the page submit, you'll have an issue.

Change part of your code to:

```
$('#subscribe').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

This should only do the AJAX submit, and not refresh the page.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2q8pspwpmujy5b/Screenshot%202018-03-09%2016.03.14.png?dl=0]

I was also able to submit via FireFox by changing `button type="submit"` to `button type="button"`, so that it won't natively submit the page on press.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a CSRF token to your form.  Assuming this is a blade file:

```
<form id="subscribe-form" class="footer-sign-up" action="/subscribe" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" id="fname" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="lname" required>
  <input id="footer-email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" required>
<input type="submit" id="subscribe" class="signupbtn" value="sign up">
```

When a page in Laravel loads, you can print a CSRF or Cross Site Request Forgery token which is good for a certain amount of time.  Any POST request needs to have a current one of these, otherwise Laravel will give you a page expired error.

Comment: This is correct, but wouldn't really explain why that works in Chrome/Safari and not Firefox though. Would it?

Comment: Testing that now, seems to face same result. first try. will do again now.

Comment: Do I need to add this line in my meta section ? on my master.balde.php ?

Comment: Trying that now.

Comment: @TimLewis no, it doesn't explain that.  Nor can I - but I know that error when I see it, so figured that would be the place to start.

Comment: Same result. :(

Comment: Some thing related to ur problem [CSRF TOKEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200209/2336835)